# Display tags summary by weekly or daily counts

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-experience

The [tags summary](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page shows tags ordered by total number of questions. Links to other views are available in the top right corner. It looks like daily and weekly counts are also being kept. But can the tags also be displayed ordered by weekly or daily counts? I couldn't figure out how to do that.

[image: tags summary]

Comment: Seems like userscript territory - not sure this is something SE should throw their resources on, but at the same time it does not lack merit completely. Consider posting a script request on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: @OlegValter - I will research and consider your suggestion. I never heard of *userscript* before. Maybe this could be a fun little project for myself.

Comment: userscripts are quite a prominent part of the network's lifecycle given that it sometimes takes literal decades for SE to implement something... There is even an [old meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19495/786798) dedicated to that :) If you decide to DIY it, do publish it once ready to get some well-deserved recognition!